# Using a Picker in a Form inside an Sheet does not work

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios14, xcode12

I need to use a picker in a form inside a sheet. But this does not work. If I click on the picker I get not into the selection of the Elements.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Sheet", action: {
            showSheet.toggle()
        })
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet, content: {
            SecondView()
        })
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Picker(selection: .constant(1), label: Text("Picker")) {
                Text("1").tag(1)
                Text("2").tag(2)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It requires `NavigationView`, ie

```
    .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet, content: {
        NavigationView {
           SecondView()
        }
    })
```

alternate is to embed `Form` in `NavigationView` directly in `SecondView`.

Comment: Perfect, this solved my issue. Thank you very much.